# Upload cover photo on facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I searched in graph api but couldn't find how to set cover photo on facebook fan page?

I want to set a cover photo ***directly*** like https://www.pagemodo.com/

I am using [facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)
I searched online and I found this [link](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/03/12/facebook-api-updating-the-page-cover-image-programmatically/)

it seam like it is using deprecated api.

Thanks for any help and suggestion in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update a Page's cover image. Read the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Updating